# Plotly - is possible to put Y-title inside of the chart?

Tags: python, plotly

Is it possible to insert the y-title inside of the chart?

[image: plotly chart]

This is a code example:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", color="sex")
fig.show()
```

I've tried modifying the layout but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can add it as an annotation.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", color="sex")
fig.add_annotation(
    xref="x domain",
    yref="y domain",
    x=0,
    y=0.5,
    textangle=-90,
    text=fig.layout.yaxis.title.text,
    showarrow=False,
).update_layout(yaxis_title="")
```

[image]